# Compiler Version not Found After Downloading

Tags: truffle-compile

When I `truffle compile`, it says "Error: Could not find a compiler version matching ^0.8.11". I did some research and installed solc (`npm install -g solc@0.8.11`), but it didn't fix the error.

In my smart contract I have `pragma solidity ^0.8.11;` declared at the top, and `solcjs --version` outputs `0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang`. I also have the following in my project folder's truffle-config.js:

```
module.exports = {

  networks: {
    //All code in here is commented out by default
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.11",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  },
}
```

This GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/4431) determined that issue was a permissions error where Solidity couldn't read from the compilers folder, but I own the truffle folder & gave everybody read+write permissions in an attempt to allow Solidity to find the compiler inside:

```
15:21:38 [<user>@<server>1t2:1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules]
$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  3 vabzbt teusers 236 Feb 22 14:51 solc
drwxr-xr-x  6 vabzbt teusers 180 Feb 21 14:42 truffle
```

Why is Truffle still unable to find the version of solc that I installed? I tried removing the `^` or changing it to `>` in my pragma solidity statement & truffle-config info but neither of those worked. fwiw, this is on an enterprise machine that can't connect to the internet, and is mostly limited to internal mirrors of repos & such.

Comment: Can you share the truffle-config.js file? What's `truffle version` output? Truffle should download the compiler in the project files, so you shouldn't need to download them separately with `npm -g ..`.

Comment: ``truffle version`` gives Truffle 5.5.1, Ganache 7.0.1, Solidity 0.8.11, Node 10.19.0, Web3.js 1.5.3. I edited above to show the full truffle-config.js

Comment: I'd suggest to start with an empty project in a new folder just copying the truffle-config.js and then start adding the sol files. If it fails with just the config file then there's a problem with truffle installation.

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution!

I determined that this was a proxy error, but I don't know how to solve it. When `truffle compile` was run, it had issues connecting to the internet to get potential compiler versions.

As a workaround, You can download the relevant Solidity version at https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/tree/gh-pages/bin, and put it in ~/.config/truffle/compilers/node_modules. It does NOT work to download solc through npm and move it from /usr/local/lib/node_modules to the /.config/truffle/... folder.